# How to split a column by delimiter

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-list, column-validation, list-validation

I am working on a column in SharePoint List. Let's name this column as Column A.
I need help to split this column by delimiter which is "-" into several columns.
Here is the sample of column A:

```
    Column A          
    -----------------|
    5675-100345-9967
    7788556-5555-133
    50505-985-1000088
```

I need help to split this column by delimiter which is "-" into several columns.
Really appreciate if anyone can help to solve this.

Tried to use LEFT or RIGHT function with calculated column but i think it is only useful when the digit is consistent.

Comment: can you please add your expected output?

Comment: Do you have any flow/workflow running on this list? it will be easy to separate it using workflow and save in different columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use flow in SharePoint online to accomplish your requirement:

My test List:

[image]

My flow:

[image]

Compose function as shown below:

```
split(triggerBody()?['ColumnA'],'-')?[0]

split(triggerBody()?['ColumnA'],'-')?[1]

split(triggerBody()?['ColumnA'],'-')?[2]
```